# How to fix: [Suspicious state from syntax checker python-mypy: Flycheck checker python-mypy returned 2, but its output contained no errors]

Tags: elpy

I keep having following warning message, even I have the recent version of `python-mypy` not sure why this warning message is generated; is there any way to fix this:

```
Suspicious state from syntax checker python-mypy: Flycheck checker python-mypy returned 2, but its output contained no errors:
utils.py: error: Source file found twice under different module names: 'Program.utils' and 'utils'
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

Try installing a more recent version of python-mypy, and please open a bug report if the issue persists in the latest release.
Thanks!
```

---

pip-setup:

```
$ pip freeze | grep mypy
flake8-mypy==17.8.0
mypy==0.790
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
```

output of `elpy-config` within the `emacs`:

```
Elpy Configuration

Emacs.............: 26.3
Elpy..............: 1.34.0
Virtualenv........: venv (/home/alper/venv)
Interactive Python: python3 3.7.5 (/home/alper/venv/bin/python3)
RPC virtualenv....: rpc-venv (/home/alper/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv)
 Python...........: python 3.7.5 (/home/alper/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv/bin/python)
 Jedi.............: 0.17.2
 Rope.............: 0.16.0
 Autopep8.........: 1.5.4
 Yapf.............: 0.30.0
 Black............: 20.8b1
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/home/alper/venv/bin/flake8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this message because Flycheck ran mypy to see if your code was correct and while mypy returned an error code, it didn't print out a list of errors (at least not as far as Flycheck could tell.)

The error message includes the output from mypy:

```
utils.py: error: Source file found twice under different module names: 'Program.utils' and 'utils'
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

A human might interpret this as an error message, I suppose, but it doesn't match any of the regular expressions that Flycheck uses to look for errors. You could update those regular expressions yourself, or even [file a bug](https://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/user/troubleshooting.html#flycheck-warns-about-non-zero-exit-code-but-no-errors) asking the Flycheck developers to fix it.

Comment: Is there anyway to disable the warning message? or prevent it to pop-up on the minibuffer

Comment: You could fix the error found by mypy. Otherwise, look in the flycheck documentation.

Comment: seems like removing `__init__.py` file solved the warning message

Comment: For me it was the opposite : adding a (missing) `__init__.py` in the file's folder.